# R - Count only the number of transactions within the last year

Tags: r

Using the RFM R Package, is there a way where I can limit the transaction_count to just count the transactions in the last year from analysis date?

https://github.com/rsquaredacademy/rfm/blob/master/R/rfm-table-transaction.R
https://github.com/rsquaredacademy/rfm

```
result <-
    data %>%
    dplyr::select(!! cust_id, !! odate, !! revenues) %>%
    dplyr::group_by(!! cust_id) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(
      date_most_recent = max(!! odate), amount = sum(!! revenues),
      transaction_count = dplyr::n()
    ) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(
      recency_days = (analysis_date - date_most_recent) / lubridate::ddays()
    ) %>%
    dplyr::select(
      !! cust_id, date_most_recent, recency_days, transaction_count,
      amount
    ) %>%
    magrittr::set_names(c("customer_id", "date_most_recent", "recency_days", "transaction_count", "amount"))
```

My dataset looks like this:

```
customer_id    date         amount
111            21/03/2019   10.50
111            10/11/2018   9.50
111            05/06/2017   50.70
```

I want to make sure that transaction_count only looks back up to a year from the analysis date. For example, if analysis date is 22/03/2019, then transaction count is 2.

Answer (score 0):

Clarifying your note - "Just count the transactions in the last year from analysis date?", assuming that you expect to limit transaction count between start date(21/03/2018) and analysis date (22/03/2019) in your example, add a note in the comments if you have a different requirement. I suggest you limit records in the input data itself rather than thinking to modify it in the [RFM package code](https://github.com/rsquaredacademy/rfm/blob/master/R/rfm-table-transaction.R) which you have put in your question, an example of R scripts for your reference given below.

```
#Define analysis window, ******before passing data to RFM package****
#Referring 365 days to catch up last one year period
analysis_period_days <- 365

#assign static value for analysis_date
#Or you can go with analysis_date <- Sys.Date()
#Or you also can give as a parameter if you have requirement to use past date as analysis date.
analysis_start_date <- analysis_date - analysis_period_days
analysis_end_date <- analysis_date

#Use analysis_start_date and analysis_end_date for filtering the records while fetching from DB, 
#Or directly apply in your DataFrame before calling RFM method

####RFM pcakge call here#######
```